# Mobile Browser View Disable/Prevent entering white spaces inside input box using Javascript

Tags: javascript

The below code only working in web view, but not in mweb browser

```
onKeyPress={(e) => {
  var startPos = e.currentTarget.selectionStart;
  if (e.which === 32 && startPos == 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: which mobile browser?

Comment: @MattEllen Chrome

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Would it be ok if the speces where removed after the editing (on submit) or that a value only was allowed without spaces (required and with a pattern attribute)?

Comment: @chrwahl If user entered mobile space button, then input box not allowed to enter spaces at the beginning (1st position)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function()
{
  let inp = document.querySelector('input');
  inp.addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
  {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.trimStart();
  });
})();
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

If you try to put a space at the start of the text box then it will be removed. In fact any whitespace will.